# django forms doubt

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here, I am a bit confused with forms in Django. I have information for the form(a poll i.e the poll question and options) coming from some db_table - table1 or say class1 in models. Now the vote from this poll is to be captured which is another model say class2. So, I am just getting confused with the whole flow of forms, here i think. How will the data be captured into the class2 table?

I was trying something like this.

> def blah1()
>             get_data_from_db_table_1()
>             x = blah2Form()
>             render_to_response(blah.html,{...})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Forms have nothing to do with models in Django**. They are just class meant to get informations from a dictionary (often `request.POST`) and check if each data linked to a key match a type and a format (e.g: is this a string of the form "bla@foo.tld").

You can ask django to create a form from a model, and in that case it will do its checking job, then if the data match, it will create a model, fill it and save it.

**If a form is not created from a model, it will do nothing but checking**. It will save nothing.

If it is created from a model, it will create a new instance of this particular model instance and save it.

If you want something more complicated, like, pre fill a form from various models or according to some conditions, or, say, you need to save several models according to the result of one form, you must do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I go about saving instances in cases of forms which aren't part of any model and involves including data in various tables(may be various models) ?

Comment: Either you override the "save()" method of your form and you do the dirty work here, or you connect a callback function doing it to the "post_save" signal of your form.